# C fopen mode read+write+create

Tags: c, fopen

I want:

> 1. file to be created if it does not exist, `not overwritten if it does`.
> 2. to read and write and `fseek` where ever I want

and I can not find out valid mode — "w+", "rw" "rwb+" "r+b" "w+b" "a+" or what?

The basic level '`open`' that performs well is:

```
int fd =open("fname", O_RDWR | O_CREAT, 0666);
```

but I would like to know `fopen alternative`.
Every mode letters [w, r, a, +] combination I tried will either overwrite contents, or fseek-fwrite not write where it should. "a+" will always append no matter what `fseek` sets... "rw+" works ok, but does not create nonexistent file ...etc.

Update: to clarify why for example "a+" is NOT a solution:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{  FILE *fp =fopen("aaa.txt", "a+");
   fwrite("aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa", 1, 10, fp);
   fseek(fp, 5, SEEK_SET);
   fwrite("AAA", 1, 3, fp);
   fclose(fp);
   return 0;
}
runned with: $ rm aaa.txt; gcc test.c && ./a.out && cat aaa.txt && echo .
produces wrong result:  aaaaaaaaaaAAA.
     result should be:  aaaaaAAAaa
```

Update2: summary... minimal functions that i end up with:

```
FILE *fopenrwc(char*n) {FILE*f=fopen(n,"a");if(f)fclose(f),f=fopen(n,"r+");return f;}
or:
FILE *fopenrwc(char*n) {return fdopen(open(n,O_RDWR|O_CREAT,0666),"r+");}
```

Comment: Why `a+` did not suite for you?

Comment: Please clarify why "a+" does not work.

Comment: @SouravGhosh "a+" was my first choice, but in file with contents, fseek(0), write(buf)... appending to the end of file instead of begining. it appends no mather what fseek and ftell says.

Comment: If you're on a sufficiently POSIX-like machine to be able to use `open()`, don't underestimate the benefits of [`fdopen()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fdopen.html) which would allow you to use `open()` with the options you showed and then create a file stream to use that file.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler thanks, fdopen is great advice. Still, if my tests are right,  this question should stay here to show stupidity of "mode" chars.

Comment: Do you want the `fopen` to fail if the file already exists?

Comment: Note that `rw+` is not a valid mode.  If you're (un)lucky, it gets treated as `r+`.  You may be best off trying `r+` and if that fails using `w+`; that opens a small window of vulnerability where someone might create a file that you then clobber with the `w+` option.  This is the way it used to be necessary to work; originally, you called `open()` — in the days before there was an `O_CREAT` — and if that failed, then you used `creat()` instead. That's a _long_ time ago, though — see 'UNIX Programming' in [7th Edition UNIX Programmer's Manual Vol 2](http://plan9.bell-labs.com/7thEdMan/).

Comment: You should use [access](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/access.2.html) to grant that the file exits and the user can access it.

Comment: If you want the finer controls, such as `O_EXCL`, or specialized properties such as `O_DSYNC` or `O_NOCTTY`, or even control over the permissions on the created file other than the default as modified by `umask()`, then `open()` plus `fdopen()` is the practically the only way to go.

Comment: @LPs: In general, you should _not_ use `access()`.  It leaves open a window of vulnerability because there is a TOCTOU — Time of Check, Time of Use — gap between the use of `access()` and `open()`.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler actually, if you sure that there is no solution with single fopen, i will mark your possible "no you can not, ... use open+fdopen combination" answer because it helped me.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz no, i do not want fopen to fail on existing file. I want simple Read&Write functions, and just to cover initial case - creating.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler It's true, I know it. But is this the case of considering a so high level race condition hacking technique? Just my consideration.

Comment: In case of using access function, take a look at [this good answer](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/42659/how-is-using-acces-opening-a-security-hole) that gives all infos about the security of that function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you review the manual page for [`fopen()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fopen.html), none of the standard open mode strings meets your requirements.

If you're on a sufficiently POSIX-like machine to be able to use [`open()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/open.html), don't underestimate the benefits of [`fdopen()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fdopen.html) which would allow you to use `open()` with the options you showed and then create a file stream to use that file.

Note that `"rw+"` is not a valid mode. If you're (un)lucky, it gets treated as `r+`.

If you can't use `fdopen()` for some reason, you may be best off trying `r+` and if that fails using `w+`; that opens a small window of vulnerability where someone might create a file that you then clobber with the `w+` option — or creates a symlink so you end up creating a file where you didn't intend to do so.

This is the way it used to be necessary to work with `open()`; originally, you called `open()` — in the days before there was an `O_CREAT` — and if that failed, then you used [`creat()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/creat.html) instead. That's a long time ago, though — see 'UNIX Programming' in [7th Edition UNIX Programmer's Manual Vol 2](http://plan9.bell-labs.com/7thEdMan/).

In general, testing with [`access()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/access.html) doesn't help.   It leaves open a window of vulnerability because there is a TOCTOU — Time of Check, Time of Use — gap between the use of `access()` and `open()` (or `fopen()`).  This is also the trouble with `open()` and `creat()`, or two calls to `fopen()`.

If you want the finer controls, such as `O_EXCL`, or specialized properties such as `O_DSYNC` or `O_NOCTTY`, or even control over the permissions on the created file other than the default as modified by [`umask()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/umask.html), then `open()` plus `fdopen()` is practically the only way to go.

Answer (score 5):

There is no direct way to meet your requirement with a simple `fopen`. IMHO, you best choice is to first use a low level `open` to create the file, and then use a `fdopen` (as suggested by Jonathan Leffler) to get a `FILE *` that can then be used with all the C library IO functions:

```
int fd =open("fname", O_RDWR | O_CREAT, 0666);
FILE *fp = fdopen(fd, "r+");
/* Ok, you can do what you want with fp */
```